# javascript/jquery shortening a string without cutting word off

Tags: javascript, jquery

say i had the string text = "this is a long string i cant display" i want to trim it down to 10 characters but if it doesnt end with a space finish the word i don't want the string variable to look like this "this is a long string i cant dis" i want it to finish the word until a space occurs. I'm trying this which was suggested by other people but .replace doesn't seem to be working but .length does? I read somewhere that javascript functions don't work inside jquery functions but i still don't understand why .length works

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.article').each(function(index){
        var text = $(this).children('p').text()
        var maxLength = 6;
        var url = $(this).find('.article-link').attr('href');

        alert(text.replace(/^(.{1}[^\s]*).*/, "$1"));
        var trimmedString = text.substr(0, maxLength);
        var text = trimmedString.substr(0, Math.min(trimmedString.length, trimmedString.lastIndexOf(" ")));

        //var text = text.substring(0, 80);
        //text = text.replace(/^(.{10}[^\s]*).*/, "$1");

    });
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript shorten string without cutting words](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5454235/javascript-shorten-string-without-cutting-words)

Comment: yes, i wasnt sure how to delete the other topic it wasn't as descriptive as this one and had no code.

Answer (score 0):

Seo duit, a chara:

```
var str = "The rain in Spain falls mainly on the plain.";

var l = 10;
while (str.length > l && str.substr(l-1,1) != " ") l++;

alert(str.substr(0,l));
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript functions most definitely do work inside jQuery functions. It looks like your regex might be the issue, if the replace function isn't working for you.

This code works:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.article').each(function(index) {
        var text = $(this).children('p').text();
        var maxLength = 6;
        var reg = new RegExp('^(.{' + maxLength + '}[^\\s]*).*');
        alert(text.replace(reg, "$1"));
    });
});
```

[Here's a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/Yc3mf/)

Comment: i was trying to use new RegExp but i must've been doing it wrong.

Comment: See it doesn't work with my div im not sure why
http://jsfiddle.net/Yc3mf/1/

might've figured out the problem for some reason the text had to be in front of the <p> tag and couldn't be on the line below same with closing tag
heres example
http://jsfiddle.net/Yc3mf/3/

Comment: This is the regular expression you want. It'll ignore the whitespace and new line characters before the paragraph content. `new RegExp('^[\\s]*(.{' + maxLength + '}[^\\s]*).*')` @josh