# Cut a string after n characters, but if it's in the middle of a word cut the whole word

Tags: javascript, jquery, character, truncate

I'm trying to make a JS function that cuts a string after n characters - that works. The problem is if it's in the middle of a word it looks bad, so I need your help making it cut the whole word if it's the middle of it.

My code so far:

```
if($('#desc').text().length > 505){
  str = $("#desc").text();
  $('#desc').text(str.substring(0, 505)).append('...');
}
```

P.S

- #desc is the div that contains my string.
- you can use jQuery.

Comment: See also the related duplicate: ["javascript shorten string without cutting words"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5454235/331508).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
function cut(n) {
    return function textCutter(i, text) {
        var short = text.substr(0, n);
        if (/^\S/.test(text.substr(n)))
            return short.replace(/\s+\S*$/, "");
        return short;
    };
}
$('#desc').text(cut(505));
```

Comment: I must be missing something because this does not work for me. In my experience if just removes the final word in the results. If the last word is 'currently' and the length cuts it at 'cur', it removes 'cur'. However, if the length cuts it at the full word 'currently' with no space at the end, it STILL removes that whole word.

Comment: @jkupczak What comes after the word 'currently' in your example? Can you provide a complete example call (as code) that turns up unexpected results, please?

Comment: My apologies, I did the math wrong! This actually works great.

Answer (score 7):

The **lastIndexOf** method can find the last space character in a string,

and passing a second argument sets an upper limit.

```
var cutat= string.lastIndexOf(' ',505);
if(cutat!=-1)string=string.substring(0,cutat)+'...';
//else the string is shorter than 505 (or has no spaces...)
```

Comment: The second argument of String.lastIndexOf() is the index from which to begin the search, not the upper limit. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf

Comment: The same source states:The calling string is searched backward, starting at the index argument.

Comment: @kennebec is right! The direction is **backwards** and therefore `lastIndexOf` is most suitable for the job. To clarify:
`var longString = "Not that long but still needs cutting";`
`console.log(longString.length, longString.lastIndexOf(' ', 15));`
`// prints 37 13`

Answer (score 2):

It's a combination of a [`for` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for), [`charAt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt), and a means of testing the character against ones you consider to be word delimiters. I'll use a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) for that:

```
function splitString(str, index) {
  var delim = /\s|[,\.]/; // Put any other character you consider
                          // a non-word char in the brackets.
                          // The initial \s is any whitespace, so
                          // space, tab, newline, etc.
  var ch;
  var i;

  // Loop until we find a matching delimiter or we run out of string    
  for (i = index;
       i >= 0 && !delim.test(str.charAt(i));
       --i) {
    // No body
  }
  if (i < 0) {
    // No break before, split word in middle
    return index;
  }
  return i + 1;
}
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ijiwav) | [source](http://jsbin.com/ijiwav/edit)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to have a look at [Cutter.js](https://github.com/tcorral/Cutter.js/)

> Cutter.js is a library used for truncating HTML code to limit its
>   length, by word number, without losing the markup.

Comment: Thanks, but i dont know the numbers of words i want only the number of characters.

Answer (score 0):

This simple function will work in any situation, plus adding 3 dots if needed :

```
function shortenString(source_string, max_length) {
    var short = source_string.substr(0, max_length);
    if (/^\S/.test(source_string.substr(max_length)))
        return short.replace(/\s+\S*$/, "") + '...';
    return short;
};
```

Example:

```
var title = "This function will work in any situation";
var short = shortenString(title, 30);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
  
    var texte = `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc eu magna at justo bibendum accumsan. Aliquam quam metus, hendrerit eget commodo at, sagittis eu lectus. Nunc quis purus urna. Etiam sollicitudin aliquam dui, vel rutrum ligula tincidunt id. In elementum ultricies ex ut bibendum. Proin ac purus id lorem pharetra commodo. Curabitur euismod commodo eleifend. Proin porttitor aliquet massa eu dapibus. Phasellus vitae tempor nibh. Donec venenatis ligula dui, at eleifend urna facilisis sed. Proin sollicitudin vehicula mi aliquam interdum. Quisque in erat purus. Ut ut ipsum nec odio mollis maximus. Vivamus nec ultricies mi, ut posuere augue.`;
    
    function cut(n,text) {
        if(n<text.length){
          while(text[n] != " " && n>0){
            n--;
          }
          return text.substr(0,n);
        }else{
          return text;
        }

  }
    
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = cut(5,texte);
```

```html
<p id="result"></p>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function cutAt(text, n) {
    if(text.length > n){
        for (; " .,".indexOf(text[n]) !== 0; n--){
        }
        return text.substr(0, n) + '...';
    }
    return text;
}
$('#desc').text(cutAt($('#desc').text(), 505));
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but unfortenatly its not working, why is the for loop empty?

Comment: The for loop has to be `for (; " .,".indexOf(text[n]) !== 0; n--);`. Currently its an endless loop.

Comment: @GodLesZ, your loop is identical to mine, the only difference is syntactic sugar, whether you use ";" or "{}". It's a bad practice to have only ";", especially in the same line, 'cause it's easy to "read" it by mistake that the next line is in the loop, that's why I'm used to have the "{}" and in 2 lines.

Comment: @Gavriel strange, I could swear the loop header was different and caused an endless loop.. Anyways, it's correct now, ideed!