# Prefer new lines to long lines

Tags: javascript, css

I would like to control the way a text is displayed in box, preferring new lines to long lines, but still allowing long lines.

Here's some examples: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jiCxo

[image]

- In #1, there's a "long" text and long lines. That is how I want it to behave.
- In #2, there's a short text and one long line. I don't like it.

I would like:

- ## 2 to be like #3 without having to add that `<br>` manually.
- to use the same HTML & CSS for both "long" and short texts.

Also, I would like the first line to be the shortest, not the last one: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/irFcK.

Any ideas?

(if, as I fear, it is not possible using only CSS, I am open to a nice JavaScript solution)

Comment: Are two lines the maximum?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I would prefer a solution without maximum, but I think it is safe to take 4 lines as a maximum for my use case.

Comment: I don't think it's possible with only CSS... But lets see.

Comment: Well, if there is no other way, I will look for a progressive enhancement solution with some JavaScript, but I would obviously prefer a full CSS solution. About the maximum, I could see a solution taking maximum 2 short lines while allowing more long lines if that helps.

Comment: Do you always want at least 2 lines? How many words minimum?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. If the text is very short (e.g. "Cras pretium"), I only want one line. One word minimum. It is user generated content.

Comment: @olivier remember to accept/up vote if my answer works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by [TMP's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18704096/prefer-new-lines-to-long-lines/18704708#18704708) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3738490/finding-line-wraps/3744583#3744583) to another question, I came up with this script that works great in most situations but still has some quirks…

```
var minimum_gap = 5; // Minimum gap on the last line to try to put it on the first.

$(".box h1").each(function() {
    var h1 = $(this),
        text = h1.text(),
        words = text.split(' '),
        lines = [],
        first_word = [],
        l = 0,
        i = 0;

    // Adding a span to measure the width
    h1.wrapInner('<span>');
    var span = h1.find('span');

    // Put the first word in the span and save the height
    span.text(words[0]);
    var height = h1.height();

    // Measure width of each line
    for(var i = 1; i < words.length; i++){
        span.append(' ' + words[i]);

        // If there's a new line
        if(h1.height() > height){
            lines[l] = span.width();
            span.text(words[i]);
            l++;
        }
    }
    // Last line
    lines[l] = span.width();

    var nb_lines = lines.length;
        ideal_line_width = 0;

    if(nb_lines == 1) {
        // If the line is "long", make it two
        if(span.width() >= h1.parent().width()/2) {
            ideal_line_width = h1.width()/2;
            nb_lines = 2;
        }
    }
    else {
        // Compute the average lines width (except for the last one)
        var sum = 0;
        for(l=0;l<(nb_lines-1);l++) {
            sum += lines[l];
        }
        var avg_width = sum/(nb_lines-1);

        // If last line is shorter than the average
        if(lines[nb_lines-1] < avg_width) {
            var gap = avg_width - lines[nb_lines-1];

            // Spread the gap among the lines
            gap /= nb_lines;

            if(gap > minimum_gap) {
                ideal_line_width = avg_width - gap;
            }
        }
    }

    // Let's make the wanted adjustments
    if(ideal_line_width != 0) {

        // Determining which is the first word of each line, beginning at the end in order to get the shortest one first
        l = nb_lines-1;
        span.empty();
        for(i=words.length-1;i>=0;i--) {
            span.prepend(words[i] + ' ');
            if(span.width() > ideal_line_width) {
                // If there's a new line, we cancel the last word
                if(h1.height() > height) {
                    i++;
                }
                span.empty();
                first_word[l] = i;
                l--;
            }
        }

        // Applying the results
        span.remove();
        l = 1;
        for(i=0;i<words.length;i++) {
            h1.append(' ' + words[i]);
            if(first_word[l] == i+1) {
                h1.append('<br>');
                l++;
            }
        }

    }
    // Or just display the text
    else {
        span.remove();
        h1.text(text);
    }

});
```

You can [see it in action here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Cdrsp). Unfortunately, I still don't like #8 and #13. Tips and improvements are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I made a quick function that should do what you want.  I commented it so you know what's going on.

```
$(".box h1").each(function() {
  // Check if one line
  if($(this).height() <= parseInt($(this).css('line-height'))){
    // Check if width is greater than %50 of parent
    if($(this).width() >= $(this).parent().width()/2){
      // Adjust width to put it on two lines
      $(this).width($(this).parent().width()/2)
    }
  }
});
```

EDIT:

To have the first line shorter than the second line, you have to do something a bit more complex.  I used cut from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10751483/1197246).  This should be pretty close to what you want.

```
$(".box h1").each(function() {
  // Check if one line
  if($(this).height() <= parseInt($(this).css('line-height'))){
    // Check if width is greater than %50 of parent
    if($(this).width() >= $(this).parent().width()/2){
      // First find approximately where you want it
      place = Math.round($(this).val().length/2);         // Might need a parseFloat
      // Find nearest end of word in correct direction
      original = $(this);
      first = original.text(cut(place));

      end = first.val().length
      start = $(this).val().length - end
      second = $(this).substr(start,end)

      // Place a break tag in the middle to put it on two lines
      $(this).html(first + <br> + second)
    }
  }
});
```

Here's cut

```
function cut(n) {
    return function textCutter(i, text) {
        var short = text.substr(0, n);
        if (/^\S/.test(text.substr(n)))
            return short.replace(/\s+\S*$/, "");
        return short;
    };
}
```

This code uses a `<br>` to break up two lines (with the second longer)

EDIT2:

It's impossible to have the line lengths be different without a `<br>` or some other way of adding a new line.  If you like it better I can change it so it uses multiple `<h1>` tags, which I think will automatically kick the each addition tag to a new line

Comment: Seems to work, here's a quick test: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FmCiE (I made some correction to your code and added line-height property in CSS).

Comment: awesome, I updated it to include your changes (let me know if I missed one!)

Comment: It is `h1` instead of `h3`, but that's not a big deal. However, while trying with more examples, I faced a new problem (not especially linked to your solution): I would like the shortest line to be the first, not the last. Have you got any ideas to solve this one?

Comment: I meant I don't want to add a `<br>` manually. Since I will be using some JavaScript, it is okay (and better than to `<h1>`, in my opinion). Thank you for your answer. It seems like it will only work for one or two lines, but I will play with it tomorrow (UTC+2 here), try to extend it if necessary and let you know how it worked out.

Comment: yeah i was still coding for the possibility of 2 lines, ill fix it so it can handle multiple

Comment: See my answer to see what I came up with, inspired by your script.

Answer (score 1):

I have come up with a solution which utilizes a [still fairly unknown JS library named MediaClass](https://github.com/jonathantneal/MediaClass) which enables the use of media queries with specific elements on the page.

I think it looks pretty good the way I've set the values but you might want to fine-tune it a little by changing widths in the JS or the CSS. Here's a <kbd>[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zQT6v/3/)</kbd> for your tinkering pleasure.

The way it works:

**JS:**

```
MediaClass("large", "h1:media(this-min-width: 300px)");
MediaClass("small", "h1:media(this-min-width: 200px and this-max-width: 300px)");
```

These lines ensure that a `small` class is added to `h1` if `h1`'s width is between `200px` and `300px` and a `large` class if `h1` is wider than `300px`.

**CSS:**

```
.large:before {
    content:"\A"; 
    width: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
}
.small:before {
    content:"\A"; 
    width: 30%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

This bit adds a `:before` pseudo-element of a width depending on the width of the `h1` inside the `h1`, before the text, this moves the first line inside the `h1` over, which changes the flow of the text.

<sub>**Edit:** I fixed up the post and the fiddle to better demonstrate how this solution answers the question asked.</sub>

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't get it to work as I want for this use case (I hate #8 in your jsFiddle). This said, MediaClass looks awesome and I will definitely keep it in mind, thank you for the discovery.

Answer (score 0):

You need JavaScript to do this. CSS cannot format text based on a complex set of rules.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that with only CSS. Here's a Javscript snippet that you can try implementing to parse your strings. It's clunky and untested but allows you to have a preset both for the char length you want, as well as a word length. I'm sure you could clean it up and make it fit your needs.

```
// requires h1 field to have line-height property set
$(".box h1").each(function()
{
  // splits if over this % width
  var preset = 50;
  // indents first line to same as preset percentage
  // to attempt to make first line shorter
  var indent = String(preset) + 'px';
  // height of a standard line
  var lh = parseInt($(this).css('line-height'));
  // width of the box
  var w = $(this).parent().width() * (preset/100);

  // if the text field is one line heigh & over the preset
  if(($(this).height() <= lh) && ($(this).width() >= w))
  {
    $(this).width(w);
    $(this).css('text-indent' , indent);
  }
  // otherwise it's fine
});
```

Here's a link: http://codepen.io/jnickg/pen/szIpd

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, I must be missing something: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pgKFi (`splitString.length` seems to always return `1`)

Comment: I was missing something: `newString.split(" ")` should be `aString.split(" ")`. Still, I couldn't get it to work like I wanted, even by playing with the parameters.

Comment: It wasn't ready to run right from the beginning, because it wasn't written to run automatically. I re-wrote it, using ideas from some other working answers, for a better working solution.Please let me know what you think.

Comment: I know it wasn't designed to run automatically, that is why I added a bit of jQuery at the end to execute it on each boxes. Your new example isn't working well in the pen (#2 should look like #3), but I must say using `text-indent` is a pretty interesting idea.