# Problems with jquery - replace a too long text with "..."

Tags: jquery

I try to cut a too long text and replace it with "...".

HTML:

```
<div class="test">    
    <span>Item text goes in here but it is way too long to fit inside a select option that has a fixed width adding more</span>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$.each($('.test span'), function(key, testName) {
    var curText = $(testName).text();
    $(this).attr('title', curText);
    var lengthToShortenTo = Math.round(parseInt($(this).parent('.test').css('width'), 10) / 7.3);

    if (curText.length > lengthToShortenTo) {
        $(this).text(curText.substring((curText.length - lengthToShortenTo), curText.length) + '... ');
    }
});
```

The output of the shortened span is:

select option that has a fixed width adding more...

But I want to get the first part of the text and not the last. So this is what I want too get:

Item text goes in here but it is way too long...

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jNWS6/247/

Comment: Can you explain better what you want and what your problem is, please.

Comment: please give your question a meaningful title :-)

Comment: possible duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12371329/html-select-dropdrown-width-is-too-big

Comment: Okay, I hope it's better now :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to change this line

```
$(this).text(curText.substring((curText.length - lengthToShortenTo), curText.length) + '... ');
```

to this

```
$(this).text(curText.substring(0, lengthToShortenTo) + '... ');
```

R.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use CSS?

```
.test {
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9sQKM/)

Comment: It seems he wants it in a select drop-down and hence the CSS option doesn't work. As in http://jsfiddle.net/9sQKM/1/

Answer (score 1):

you are taking wrong part of substring, you should take first part

```
$.each($('.sedcardHolder span'), function(key, sedcardName) {
    var curText = $(sedcardName).text();
    $(this).attr('title', curText);

    var lengthToShortenTo =     Math.round(parseInt($(this).parent('.sedcardHolder').css('width'), 10) / 5.3);

    if (curText.length > lengthToShortenTo) {
        $(this).text(curText.substring(0,(curText.length - lengthToShortenTo)) + '... ');
    }
});
```