# I want option text break or equal to select width?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

[codepenlink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MW6BU.png)

How to break line of option text  and equal to select tag width.

Comment: Please don't use images to show code. This makes it very hard for us to help. Instead share the codepen link in the question description.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [html select dropdrown width is too big](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12371329/html-select-dropdrown-width-is-too-big)

Comment: yeah sorry for image !!
Here is the code pen line please give me some idea about option width .
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PexXXP

Answer (score 1):

You cannot apply formatting to the option dropdown as mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2864244/5686835)

You can however make use of something like ellipsis.

```js
var maxLength = 15;
$('#example > option').text(function(i, text) {
    if (text.length > maxLength) {
        return text.substr(0, maxLength) + '...';  
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="example" id="example">
    <option value="">This is some long text</option>
    <option value="">Short Text</option>
    <option value="">This is some really, really long text</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Is there possible to show full text with same width

Comment: No because you cannot wrap the text to a new line.

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```css
select{
    min-width: 100px;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<select>
    <option value="1"><span>content 1</span></option>
    <option value="3">Content is so long but still some remains</option>
</select>
```

[**Working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8mTdM/1052/)

Comment: I do not see any effect of css on the width. width is controlled by the content of option!

Comment: I read the question and it says make option width same as select, not the other way!

Comment: Then you didn't see result hahah.. keep calm and learn something rather than criticizing others

Comment: I'm trying, could you please tell me what does these styles doing in this code? I removed them and yet the result is same :)

Comment: Select will expand with option content size. If you don't want initial width you can remove min-width: 100px from there
like this https://jsfiddle.net/yeLfqeep/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171513/discussion-between-shakkir-and-kumar).

Comment: hahaha.. you already downvote without checking answer carefully. So why should i talk about this anyway i have already explain you.

Comment: min-width: 100px  is the only thing that is working in this.  text-overflow: ellipsis;has no effect! can you do with width: 100px? that is what the question is about