# JavaScript regex literal vs RegExp object

Tags: javascript, regex

I came a long with this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5454235/javascript-shorten-string-without-cutting-words) and would like to set the char count. Therefor I have to create the expresion as a String and use `new RegExp()`. So I change the the snippet a bit and use a new `RegExp` object

**Orginal**

```
var t = "this is a longish string of text";
t.replace(/^(.{11}[^\s]*).*/, "$1");

//result:
"this is a longish"
```

**With RegExp**

```
var t = "this is a longish string of text";
var count = 11;
t.replace(new RegExp('^(.{' + count + '}[^\s]*).*'), "$1");

//result:
"this is a longi"
```

As you can see the result of the second one is not the expected. Any hints whats the different between using a literal and using RegExp object here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a string, you need to escape the backslashes:

```
new RegExp('^(.{' + count + '}[^\\s]*).*')
```

(and you can use `\S` instead of `[^\s]`):

```
new RegExp('^(.{' + count + '}\\S*).*')
```