# How to detect line break with this RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using the RegExp from this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5454297/184883) to shorten string without cutting words. Unfortunately this dont work when there are line breaks in the tested string. Is there a way to shorten string without cutting words and also after at the first line break.

```
"this is a longish string of \n\n test".replace(/^(.{11}[^\s]*).*/, "$1"); 
//Expected output: "this is a longish"
//Actual output: "this is a longish test"
```

Comment: Can you update your question and give an example of a line break and what you would like the output to be?

Comment: What is wrong with @quotemyname's answer below?

Comment: @TrevorSenior, nothing but I asked the question at 11pm local time ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried inserting another '.replace()' before the one you've got?

Example:

```
var longString = "this is a longish<br> string of test";
longString = longString.replace(/\n/g, "").replace(/^(.{11}[^\s]*).*/, "$1");
```

Perhaps something to that effect will help? You may need to play with the formatting a little, as I'm not sure how you want the string to actually end up looking, or how the `<br>` tags in your page are formatted, etc.

Good luck!

Comment: He has updated his question to use `\n`, but the idea is the same. +1

Comment: @quotemyname could you update your answer with this: `replace(/\n/g, "")`

Comment: Updated. Sorry for the delay, didn't have time to check this until now.

Comment: @Stev: The multiline modifier (`/m`) does not make `.` match newlines, it makes the `^` and `$` anchors match at line boundaries.  You're thinking of the singleline a.k.a. DOTALL modifier (usually `/s`), but doesn't support that mode.

Comment: @Alan Moore You're right  !! Sorry about posting this ... just deleted it