# Javascript/jQuery Get first 100 characters from string, respecting full words

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, substring

I came across lots of Question regarding this , and i found solution for PHP only. There was no solution on this site for jQuery/javascript way of doing it.

What I want to do is I want to show first 100 characters but I dont want to cut the last word, as it would be meaningless.

Like say `this is myself` is the last words so it we regularly take substring and `y` is 100th word, then it would cut it like `this is my`, which would be meaning less. So I want it like `this is..`

My original code :

```
jQuery(".block-text .success-inner-content").each(function(){
    if(jQuery(this).text().length > 100){
        jQuery(this).text(jQuery(this).text().substr(0,98)+'..');
    }
});
```

here `block-text .success-inner-content` class is in loop producing list of Divs with text within it.

Comment: It is a dupe, but I do not know where the original answer is... Maybe I will find it.

Comment: Yes, it is a dupe. Just google the title of this question. _http://stackoverflow.com/q/5454235/4227915_

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `lastIndexOf` method takes a second parameter that determines where the search starts, so you don't need to cut the string down before finding the last space:

```
jQuery(".block-text .success-inner-content").each(function () {
  var text = jQuery(this).text();
  if (text.length > 100) {
    jQuery(this).text(text.substr(0, text.lastIndexOf(' ', 97)) + '...');
  }
});
```

You can also use the `text` method instead of `each` to loop the elements and set the text for each:

```
jQuery(".block-text .success-inner-content").text(function (i, text) {
  return text.length > 100 ? text.substr(0, text.lastIndexOf(' ', 97)) + '...' : text;
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Or you could do it with regex... Something like this -

```
var s = 'What I want to do is I want to show first 100 characters but I don't want to cut the last word, as it would be meaningless.';

console.log(s.match(/(.{1,19}\w)\s/)[1]+'...');
```

This matches any 20 characters, ending with a word character, and followed by a space.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

I solved myself. The solution uses `substr()` and most importantly `lastIndexOf()` functions of javascript .

```
jQuery(".block-text .success-inner-content").each(function () {
    if (jQuery(this).text().length > 100) {
        var str =  jQuery(this).text().substr(0,98);
        var wordIndex = str.lastIndexOf(" ");

        jQuery(this).text(str.substr(0, wordIndex) + '..');
    }
});
```