# Truncated a string with a number of characters without truncating words

Tags: javascript, truncate

I want to truncate a string with a limit of characters and a condition for the last character that should be a space (this way I have no truncated words)

Example :

```
var sentence = "The string that I want to truncate!";
sentence.methodToTruncate(14); // 14 is the limit of max characters 
console.log("Truncated result : " + sentence); // Truncated result : The string
```

Comment: Ok, so what have you tried so far?

Comment: yeah, we need to see an effort, we can't just write your code for you

Comment: Why don't you use substring() method in javascript?

Comment: One way this : `sentence.substring(0,sentence.length - 14));`

Comment: @Nerdvoso: I don't think that does what's suggested.  `sentence.substring(0, 14)` is closer, but ignores the issue of avoiding partial words.  A solution is not difficult, but I'd prefer to see the OP put in some effort before posting one.

Comment: I agree with @ScottSauyet, before posting anything I would like to see what OP has tried.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shorten string without cutting words in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5454235/shorten-string-without-cutting-words-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `truncate` one-liner below:

```js
const sentence = "The string that I want to truncate!";

const truncate = (str, len) => str.substring(0, (str + ' ').lastIndexOf(' ', len));

console.log(truncate(sentence, 14));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can truncate by words and given limit -

```js
String.prototype.methodToTruncate = function(n) {
    var parts = this.split(" ");
    var result = "";
    var i = 0;
    while(result.length >= n || i < parts.length) {
       if (result.length + parts[i].length > n) {
           break;
       }
       
       result += " " + parts[i];
       i++;
    }
    
    return result;
}

var sentence = "The string that I want to truncate!";
console.log("Truncated result : " + sentence.methodToTruncate(14)); // Truncated result : The string
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

First you can have a max substring of your string, and then recursively remove the letters until you find spaces.
Note that this response is made without doing monkey patching and so, not extending `String.prototype` :

```js
var sentence = "Hello a";
var a = methodToTruncate(sentence, 5); // 14 is the limit of max characters 
console.log("Truncated result : " + a); // Truncated result : The string 

function methodToTruncate(str, num) {

 if(num>= str.length){ return str;}
  var res = str.substring(0, num);
  
  while (str[res.length] != " " && res.length != 0) {
    console.log(res.length)
    res = res.substring(0, res.length-1);
  }
  return res;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)