# HTML/CSS Text Around a Corner of a DIV

Tags: html, css

So, I'm looking to do a single H1 tag to go around a container. If I use CSS rotate, I can rotate the text, but obviously only the 90 degrees, not around a div. I'm looking to keep the text in ONE H1 tag since the designer would like this to be the headline of the page and for SEO purposes.

I'm not sure if this is possible from all the research I've done. I'm a bit stumped. I figured you guys/gals would know if this would be even possible.

***FOR EXAMPLE:***
[image]

```
<h1>Latest News</h1>
<div>Blue Square</div>
```

Comment: Yikes, that's a tough one. Since the headline is dynamic, how do you want to decide where to separate the vertical and horizontal parts? I think this could be possible with some very detailed JS, but not otherwise.

Comment: You are right, the text would be dynamic, I even forgot about that element...

Comment: With meta tags you can set the title for SEO purpose, and do whatever you want with the rest of your html tags. So the KISS solution is `<meta property="og:title" content="Whatever title for SEO" />` and 2 `h1` tags with some simple css

Answer (score 4):

- Position your box `relative` (with some `margin` room for the *offset* heading text)
- Position your heading `absolute` with negative top `-1.1em`
- Create a `<span>` (inside the heading) for the **rotated vertical text**
- Position your SPAN absolute at right `100% + 1.1em`
- `transform` **rotate** you SPAN on the origin `right top` by `-90deg`

```css
/*QuickReset*/*{margin:0;box-sizing:border-box;}html,body{min-height:100%;font:14px/1.4 sans-serif;}

.box {
  position: relative;
  margin: 3em;
  width: 140px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #0bf;
}
.box h1 {
  position: absolute;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 2em; /* play only with this value. don't touch the rest! */
  top: -1.1em;
}
.box h1 span{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.35em;
  right: calc(100% + 1.1em);
  transform-origin: right top;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <h1><span>Latest</span> News</h1>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <h1><span>Special</span> Offers!</h1>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <h1><span>Edge case with</span> some long text</h1>
</div>
```

#### Wrap into `<span>` automatically (server-side)

If you're pulling **unknown length titles** i.e. from a CMS, I suggest you split your string in half- ***word-aware!*** in order to determine the *first-half word/s* that need to be wrapped in `span`

**Example using PHP:**

```
<?php

/**
 * Wrap first half of a sentence into <span>, word-aware! 
 */

function span_first_half($s) {
  $n = floor(strlen($s)/2);
  preg_match(("/.{{$n}}\\S*/"), $s, $a);
  $b = substr($s, strlen($a[0]));
  return "<span>$a[0]</span>$b";
}
```

**PHP - use like:**

```
<h1><?= span_first_half("Edge case with some long text") ?></h1>
<h1><?= span_first_half("This is cool!") ?></h1>
```

Will result in:

> `<h1><span>Edge case with</span> some long text</h1>`
>   `<h1><span>This is</span> cool!</h1>`

---

**JavaScript** - Use like

```js
function span_first_half(s) {
  const n = Math.floor(s.length/2),
    a = s.match(RegExp(".{"+n+"}\\S*"))[0],
    b = s.substr(a.length);
  return `<span>${a}</span>${b}`;
}

console.log( span_first_half("Edge case with some long text") );
console.log( span_first_half("This is cool!") );
```

<sub>The above demos are adapted from [this JavaScript example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38135381/383904)</sub>

Comment: Whoa. Holy smokes I think you might have nailed this. I want to play with what you created tomorrow at the office and read up a bit more to see how this works and report back.

Comment: ;) @Hugo sure, take your time! PS. just keep all your values in `em` unit - That way all you need to play with is the Heading's font size! Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for are `svg` elements. This is an entire different world of coding, but works as HTML. I would suggest to follow some documentation about svg. CSS is not meant for these types of manipulation.

I have create an example: [svg fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qj36mf9b/)

**HTML**

```html
<svg width="500" height="500">
  <path id="curve" d="M25,25   l125,0  0,125  -125,0  0,-125"
      style="stroke: #0D454A; fill: #0D454A;" />
  <text width="500px">
    <textPath alignment-baseline="top" xlink:href="#curve">
      This is a text example that's floating around this square
    </textPath>
  </text>
</svg>
```

To follow text around a rectangular you need to use `<path>` and `<textPath>`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer Demian. Yeah I agree, that this is a tough one. Given that we need to keep the H1 tag for SEO -- I was really trying to avoid using svg.

Answer (score 0):

i think this way can help you

```html
<div>
<h1>Latest News</h1>
Blue Square
</div>
```

but your uploaded image not loaded, please try again upload it , and reply to me to I help you

Answer (score -1):

It can be done by simple CSS transforms:

```
<style>
    * { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
    div.square { margin-left: 8em; width: 20em;
                 height: 20em; background-color: #08F; }
    h1 { margin-left: 2em; transform: translate(-3em);
         font-size: 400%;}
    h1 div { display: inline-block;
           transform: translate(1em,1em) rotate(-90deg); }
</style>
...
<h1><div>HEAD</div>ONE</h1>
<div class="square">Square</div>
```

The h1 will be treated as "HEAD ONE" text by search engines.

Comment: Why the downvotes?  This is short, simple,  and actually works.  And unlike the SVG suggestions, it doesn't hide the important h1 text from search engines.