# How do I find all the words (complete words) up to the 65 character in a string?

Tags: javascript, string, pattern-matching

I'm trying to optimize my titles for Google SEO (title tag in html).

I have product titles that are 3-4 lines long and just look like garbage. I would like to basically find the last full word before the 65 character in a sring.

So if 'foo bar baz buzz' were the middle of a long string and the "a" in "baz" were the 65th character I'd want to just exclude "baz" and everything after it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shorten string without cutting words in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5454235/shorten-string-without-cutting-words-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

This is what I ended up going with:

```
function truncateTitle(str, len = 60) {
  //get a temporal substring with the desired length
  if (str.length <= len) {
    return str;
  }

  const temp = str.substr(0, len);

  //get the last space index
  const lastSpaceIdx = temp.lastIndexOf(' ');

  //get the final substring
  return temp.substr(0, lastSpaceIdx).trim();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm! I like the other solutions, but I want to give it my own shot.

What I realized is that **if the last word is complete, there MUST be a space after it**.

So all you need to do is increment your desired length by `+1`. If the 66th character is a space, then the last word before it is complete and you **don't need to discard it**. If it isn't, then discard.

If the last char is a space, whenever you `.split()` at the spaces **it will create an empty string as a last element**, since it interprets the last space as a splitting point - so you can `.pop()` the last element safely, knowing that it's either incomplete or empty.

#### Example snippet

```js
// generates really long string with the entire alphabet
var str = new Array(100).fill('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz').join(' ');

// defines the last char you want to consider
var len = 65;

// splits the string at that length + 1
var words = str.slice(0, len + 1).split(/\s+/);

// discards last element, which is either empty or incomplete
words.pop();

// only full alphabets will be displayed
console.log(words);
```

Answer (score -1):

You should check that the string is longer than the desired length and if it is...

```
var title = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In id diam vitae enim maximus consequat sit amet eu elit. Sed.";

const substr_length = 65;

//get a temporal substring with the desired length
var temp = title.substr(0, substr_length);

//get the last space index
var ls_index = temp.lastIndexOf(" ");

//get the final substring
var short_title = temp.substr(0, ls_index).trim();

//done
```

Comment: beautiful, simple and intuitive.

Comment: actually I modified it a bit. You can use `lastIndexOf(' ');`

Comment: You are right. I modified my answer with that change.